# feasible method is stucked in infinite loop

Tags: c++, simplex

I have run the following simplex method which is written in C++ .The code is as follows :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

#define maxm 500
#define maxn 500
double inf = 1e100;
double eps = 1e-13;

int row,col;
double A[maxm][maxn];
double B[maxn];
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Simon Lo's
// Simplex algorithm on augmented matrix a of dimension (m+1)x(n+1)
// returns 1 if feasible, 0 if not feasible, -1 if unbounded
// returns solution in b[] in original var order, max(f) in ret
// form: maximize sum_j(a_mj*x_j)-a_mn s.t. sum_j(a_ij*x_j)<=a_in
// in standard form.
// To convert into standard form:
// 1. if exists equality constraint, then replace by both >= and <=
// 2. if variable x doesn't have nonnegativity constraint, then replace by
// difference of 2 variables like x1-x2, where x1>=0, x2>=0
// 3. for a>=b constraints, convert to -a<=-b
// note: watch out for -0.0 in the solution, algorithm may cycle
// eps = 1e-7 may give wrong answer, 1e-10 is better



void pivot(int m, int n, double a[maxm][maxn], int B[maxm], int N[maxn], int r, int c) {
        int i, j;
        swap(N[c], B[r]);
        a[r][c]=1/a[r][c];
        for (j=0; j<=n; j++)if (j!=c) a[r][j]*=a[r][c];
        for (i=0; i<=m; i++)if (i!=r) {
                for (j=0; j<=n; j++)if (j!=c)
                        a[i][j]-=a[i][c]*a[r][j];
                a[i][c] = -a[i][c]*a[r][c];
        }
}
int feasible(int m, int n, double a[maxm][maxn], int B[maxm], int N[maxn]) {
        int r, c, i; double p, v;
        while (1) {
                for (p=inf, i=0; i<m; i++) if (a[i][n]<p) p=a[r=i][n];
                if (p>-eps) return 1;
                for (p=0, i=0; i<n; i++) if (a[r][i]<p) p=a[r][c=i];
                if (p>-eps) return 0;
                cout<<"Sultan"<<endl;
                p = a[r][n]/a[r][c];
                for (i=r+1; i<m; i++) if (a[i][c]>eps) {
                        v = a[i][n]/a[i][c];
                        if (v<p) r=i, p=v;
                }
                pivot(m, n, a, B, N, r, c);
        }
}
int simplex(int m, int n, double a[maxm][maxn], double b[maxn], double& ret)
 {
        int B[maxm], N[maxn], r, c, i; double p, v;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) N[i]=i;
        for (i=0; i<m; i++) B[i]=n+i;
        if (!feasible(m, n, a, B, N)) return 0;
        while (1) {
                for (p=0, i=0; i<n; i++) if (a[m][i]>p)
                        p=a[m][c=i];
                if (p<eps) {
                        for (i=0; i<n; i++) if (N[i]<n)
                                b[N[i]]=0;
                        for (i=0; i<m; i++) if (B[i]<n)
                                b[B[i]]=a[i][n];
                        ret = -a[m][n];
                        return 1;
                }
                for (p=inf, i=0; i<m; i++) if (a[i][c]>eps) {
                        v = a[i][n]/a[i][c];
                        if (v<p) p=v, r=i;
                }
                if (p==inf) return -1;
                pivot(m, n, a, B, N, r, c);
        }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void read_file()
{
    freopen("Dimen.txt","r",stdin);

    scanf("%d",&row);
    scanf("%d",&col);

    row = 30 ;
    col = 100;

    cout << row << " "<<col<<endl;

    freopen("A1.txt","r",stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
         scanf("%lf",&A[i][j]);
    cout<"Completed A";

    freopen("B1.txt","r",stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
       scanf("%lf",&A[i][col]);
    }
    cout<"Completed B";

    freopen("F1.txt","r",stdin);
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        scanf("%lf",&A[row][j]);
        //B[i]=-B[i];
    }
    cout<"Completed F";


}

int main()
{
    read_file();
    double value,opt=0;
    int flag = simplex(row,col, A,B, value);
    freopen("opt.txt","r",stdin);
    scanf("%lf",&opt);
    if(flag != -1)
    {
        cout<<"The result is "<<(value+opt);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The result is infeasible";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this code runs in infinite loop . The feasible method stucks in infinite loop . How can I solve this error ? Please help me .

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I have debugged the code . The code stucked in feasible method .

Comment: Then you have to learn how to use the debugger more efficiently.

Comment: @SagorAhmed: Well, surely the debugger tells you more details about where exactly the code is "stuck". Apparently, the condition `(p>-eps)` is never met, so none of the `return`s are reached. The question is: Why is that so? Why is the condition always false?

Comment: You are not reaching either return statements. I find that it is quicker to throw out buggy code and rewrite it from scratch rather then try to patch hard to understand code.  You understand the problem better now,  The hard part is over. Now find a simpler solution that is less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by fixing the unclear bits of the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

You should not use any includes that starts with `bits/` include the standard header that will include it.

```
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
```

Using `std` is bad practice, it might confuse the compiler in large projects and select a function/template/whatever that you did not mean to.

```
#define maxm 500
#define maxn 500
```

As minimum change these to

```
#define maxm (500)
#define maxn (500)
```

So macro substitution doesn't get confused. Better use c++11 and use

```
constexpr int maxm = 500; 
constexpr int maxn = 500; 

double inf = 1e100;
double eps = 1e-13;
```

There are standard ways of finding the correct values for `inf` and `eps`

```
double inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

From you code I presume you really meant max double. 
For `eps` I wonder if you need

```
double eps = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

or

```
double eps = std::numeric_limits<double>::round_error();
```